# macOS keyboard shortcut for correcting misspelled words?

Tags: macos, mac, text-editor, spellcheck, spelling

In a Mac OS X native textfields, misspelled and typo'd words are underlined with a red squiggle.

Is there a standard **keyboard shortcut** that will correct a mispelling by selecting the most-likely correction?

This should work in all native textfields. The solution should not be limited to a single app.

[image: misspelled words in macOS document]

It's already possible to Right Click a misspelled word. I'd like a keyboard shortcut to bring up a similar feature, so that I don't have to manually Right Click each word individually.

The feature could correct each word, one-by-one, allowing you to select each correction. Or, it could use the best guess for *all* misspelled words in the document.

[image: correcting spelling via Right Click]

Answer (score 5):

You can't correct them in a single click, but you can make it start to go though them in bulk, correcting each on the way.

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>:</kbd>  [which on a UK keyboard is actually  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>;</kbd>  ] will pop up the Spelling & Grammar checker, allowing you to select each error in turn & correct it [or ignore, learn etc]

[image]

Alternatively ... Edit Menu > Spelling and Grammar > Show Spelling and Grammar

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Once you're opened this panel with a keyboard shortcut, it unfortunately still needs plenty of mouse clicks to operate. More than the right-click suggestions even. I'm hoping to find something that's automatic or driven entirely by the keyboard...

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard only solution:

1. <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> to open the spelling floating window for the next misspelled word.
2. <kbd>Ctrl ^</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd> to go to the spelling window. (See preferences image below.)
3. Use arrows to navigate to the correct spelling.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to change that word.
   (Note that if there are more misspelled words, it will loop over them)
5. Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to exit the floating window.

If like me you want to change the shortcut for moving to the floating window, this is where it is done:

[image: preferences pane - move focus to the floating window]

Comment: Dang, nice research. To add: If you want to skip a word, in the floating window, you can `^F7` to "change the way Tab moves focus" and then tab your way to the "Find Next" button.